# How to save the users progress in an array Swift with a plist

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Hey guys in my app the user clicks a button called the showfunfact() that moves them through an array of strings. When the user removes the app from multitasking or turns off the phone I want the users place to be saved and then when the reload the can pick up where they left off

```
var TechfactIndex = 0
let TechnologyfactBook = TechFactBook()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    TechfactIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("ByteLocation")
    defaults.setObject(TechfactIndex, forKey: "ByteLocation")
}

@IBAction func showFunFact() {
    if ( UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    if (TechfactIndex >= TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray.count) {  
        self.TechfactIndex = 0   
    }

    TechByteLabel.text = TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray[TechfactIndex]
    TechfactIndex++
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(TechfactIndex, forKey: "ByteLocation")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `viewDidDisappear:` is unrelated to your spec. It is not called "When the user removes the app from multitasking or turns off the phone". It is not called when the phone rings. It is not called when the user hits the home button. It's irrelevant. You've put your code in the wrong place.

What you want to do is register to hear when the *app is deactivated*. That is the moment to write information into the user defaults.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that expensive of an operation to just write to the User Defaults every time the next fun fact is viewed. So for the sake of simplicity, you could just write the new index to the `NSUserDefaults` every time they view a new fun fact.

```
@IBAction func showFunFact() {
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    TechfactIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("ByteLocation")

    if (TechfactIndex >= TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray.count) {  
        self.TechfactIndex = 0   
    }

    TechByteLabel.text = TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray[TechfactIndex]
    TechfactIndex++
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(TechfactIndex, forKey: "ByteLocation")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

**However**, the user defaults is usually reserved for preferences... so you may be better off implementing a plist (or similar simple saving option) here to store the current index.

**EDIT:** Here is a simple example on how you could use a plist to achieve this

First, create a `Property List` file in your directory, call it `Data.plist`. Make the root object a dictionary and add an NSNumber object with the key `FunFactIndex`. This will be a template for your plist on the first time a save occurs.

```
func showFunFact() {
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    // Load the next index
    var factIndex = getCurrentFunFactIndex() as Int

    if factIndex < 0 {
        println("error")
        return
    }

    if (factIndex >= TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray.count) {
        factIndex = 0
    }

    TechByteLabel.text = TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray[factIndex]
    factIndex++

    // Save the index
    let saveSuccess = saveFunFactIndex(factIndex);

    let successString = (saveSuccess) ? "success" : "failure"

    println("Save was a \(successString)")
}

func getCurrentFunFactIndex() -> Int {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Data.plist")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // Check if file exists, copy it over from the bundle if it doesn't
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "plist")
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle!, toPath: path, error:nil)
    }

    if let dataDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
        if let indexNum: AnyObject = dataDict.objectForKey("FunFactIndex") {
            return indexNum.integerValue
        }
    }

    return -1   // Something went wrong
}

func saveFunFactIndex(index: Int) -> Bool {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Data.plist")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // Check if file exists, copy it over from the bundle if it doesn't
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: "plist")
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle!, toPath: path, error:nil)
    }

    if let dataDict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
        let indexNum: NSNumber = index
        dataDict.setObject(indexNum, forKey: "FunFactIndex")
        return dataDict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    }

    return false
}
```

There are two methods I added for you; `getCurrentFunFactIndex` and `saveFunFactIndex:. Both will first check in the Documents directory of the sandbox for`Data.plist`. If that file does not exist, it will copy over the template plist that we created in the bundle. All future uses of these methods will use the`Data.plist` file that is in the Documents directory. This will allow the value to persist on subsequent app launches (removing the app from the background or turning off the device).

Comment: how would i do it with a plist

Comment: @NikhilCKanamarla See my edit on how to use a plist for saving the index